# Logged In Windows 7 Active Directory User from SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, active-directory, spring-security, windows-authentication

Simply putting it - I have a Spring-Jersey application (no front-end) deployed into Tomcat, as a service, which is installed in SQL Server 2008.

Users log into their machines (windows 7) and VPN into SQL Server.

After which they can open a KML file in Google Earth.

This will plot coordinates generated by the tomcat application, in real-time.

QUESTION - I want only users who are in a certain group in active directory to be able to use the plotting service.

How can I get the win7-username and win7-group name of the user who logged into his windows 7 machine?

My Java sits in Tomcat/SQL Server, so **.getProperty("user.name");** will get me username of the SQL server user, not the windows 7 user who is trying to access my app.

I hope this is clearer.

I appreciate your efforts.

Comment: Your question isn't really clear to me, can you simplify it? If a user is directly connected to SQL Server using Windows authentication, then the [SYSTEM_USER function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179930.aspx) returns the Windows domain and login. But if the users connect via a web service, then SQL Server can only 'see' the connection from the web service, not the end user, so you have to find some other way of identifying them.

Comment: Please see my rephrased question. Thanks much!